# Can this code be further optimized from O(n^2) to O(n)?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++14

This is the code needs to be optimized

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
      // size of cross, use odd number
      int size = 5;
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { 
          if (i==j || i+j==size-1) {
            cout << "*";
          } else {
            cout << " ";
          }
        }
        cout << "\n";
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
```

Please let me know any source or reference if any...

Comment: You need to print NxN characters, so no it can't be optimized to O(N) (unless you have some smart way of printing to specific positions on terminal in O(1) instead of printing line-wise).

Comment: `std::cout << "*   *\n * *\n  *\n * *\n*   *";` could replace your entire program.  [(godbolt link)](https://godbolt.org/z/Pddc8Kve5)

Comment: Disable line buffering at the start, so it doesn't flush each line to a system call. That alone will speed it up, in combination with the other suggestions, it would be near the limit.

Comment: @DrewDormann The length of code required to do that is still scaling with O(N^2).

Comment: I guess this is just an exercise, but this code would be particularly silly to optimize. It is bound by I/O.

Comment: As Eugene already mentioned, there's no way to do that for generic values of `N`. The actual time used doesn't matter (@doug65536).

Comment: Don't remove huge constant factors. Got it.

Comment: The only optimization that can actually speed up a lot such output test program is: `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My solution does it for generic values of N so I think you are wrong. :)

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question by the way is **NO**.

Just printing the result and nothing else is `O(N^2)`. There is absolutely no way to output `N * (N + 1)` chars in less than `O(N^2)`.

You can improve the performance of the code though by computing everything at compile time:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <array>

template <int size>
constexpr auto cross() {
    std::array<char, size * (size + 1) + 1> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { 
            if (i==j || i+j==size-1) {
                arr[i * (size + 1) + j] = '*';
            } else {
                arr[i * (size + 1) + j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        arr[i * (size + 1) + size] = '\n';
    }
    arr[arr.size() - 1] = 0;
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    // size of cross, use odd number
    const auto t = cross<5>();
    puts(t.data());
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WdWdTYcvK

This optimizes down to `puts("*   *\n * * \n  *  \n * * \n*   *\n");`, which is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Whouah, quite an advanced answer to a silly question !

Comment: @prapin well, it's quite common, that people confuse _time complexity_ with _actual time used_ for an algorithm. But people **are _"silly"_** regarding math and such commonly as well.

Comment: It was asked by an interviewer and I told it couldn't be optimised further. But, he keep on asking like there is some mathematical computation which can be done to optimise this code in a single loop.

Comment: You can loop from `0` to `size * size` and then split that into i and j. but what would be the point? Or initialize a buffer with ' ' and then use a single loop to fill in the '*'. But none of that has any bearing on the `O(N^2)` as that's a given from the output alone.